# meteor collection could not get from the server to client

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have been reading the meteor doc and but currently i am facing the below issue.

**code block 1**

```
Router.map(function() {
     this.route('quizzes', {
         path: '/quizzes',
         waitOn: function() {
             return Meteor.subscribe('quizzes');
         }
     });
 })
```

I can see the above collection from template simply by using Meteor.quizzes.find()

**Code Block 2**

**server side code is**

```
// Declare server Movies collection
Movies = new Meteor.Collection("movies");


// Seed the movie database with a few movies
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Movies.find().count() == 0) {
        Movies.insert({ title: "Star Wars", director: "Lucas" });
        Movies.insert({ title: "Memento", director: "Nolan" });
        Movies.insert({ title: "King Kong", director: "Jackson" });
    }


console.log(Meteor.movies.find().count()) //retunr 3 records
Meteor.publish('movies', function(){
        return Movies.find({});
    })
```

**routes code as follows**

```
 Router.map(function() {
      //Admin routes
      this.route('userManagement', {
        path: '/user-management',
        waitOn: function() {
          return Meteor.subscribe('users');
        }
      });
    });


when I use the users in the above block of code, It working fine. 
but when i use movies/quizzes on same route map .



  Router.map(function() {
      //Admin routes
      this.route('moviesManagement', {
        path: '/movies-management',
        waitOn: function() {
          return Meteor.subscribe('movies');
        }
      });
    });
```

But when i try to access Meteor.movies.find() nothing is coming and I think subscribe method also not returning anyhting.

I have spent a lot of time to fix but I could not find the soltioon . Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to your `movies` publication, either by using Iron Router's `waitOn` or `subscriptions` options, or by calling the subscription yourself. Notice that in the quizzes code you are waiting on the quiz subscription before running the route.

Calling the subscription manually:

```js
// on client
Meteor.subscribe('movies', function() {
  console.log(Movies.find().count()); // 3
});
```

Using Iron Router to handle your subscription:

```js
// on client
Router.route('/movies', {
  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('movies'); }
});
```

By the way, you're using the old, legacy Iron Router API. I recommend looking at the [official Iron Router guide](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working when I Meteor.subscribe('users') but not when I use Meteor.subscribe('movies').

Comment: Can you please help me If I need add any other code like configurations or something else. I have edited the actual question post

Comment: I am using the  "iron-router" "tag": "v0.7.1"

Comment: I am using the accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown and all users and notifications, I can access the all users and notifications  from client. Currently, I am using going to create brand new collection i.e movies, I can not access from client. Please help me in this

Comment: Hey, I have resolved this by writing the Meteor.subscribe('movies') method directly in the client side instead of writing in the   Meteor.subscribe('movies', function() {
  console.log(Movies.find().count()); // 3

I just wirtten the Meteor.subscribe('movies') in the folder/client/movies.js and working perfectly but I dont know th reason why it is working .. why not with routes. If possible can you help me to understand
});